# how do I create a new thread from a volley response

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have an android app that uses volley for API requests, how do I create a new thread from a volley response, so that I do not use the UI thread for creating the item on the recycler view, this is how i am currently creating new items on the recyclerview

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    courseRV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    userList.clear();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response;
                    try {
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                            String userName = jsonObject.getString("posterUserName");
                            userList.add(new RePost( name,userName));

                            adapter = new Adapter( getContext(),userList,userID,message);
                            courseRV.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception w)
                    {
                        w.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
```

Comment: Please post logcat ..

Comment: the code above works fine, but take some time to process @GokulNathKP